# Parsing Google Base XML with PHP XMLReader

Tags: php, xml, google-base

I'm trying to import a number of google base xml files into a single database, but alas, while I assumed the the Google Base XML would be a standardised format it seems that different sources create files with different structures.

Therefore, my import that can process the XML file from source A fails when applied to source B.

Is there are standard or common way to transform various Google Base XML documents into a single format?

For example, source A uses a

```
 <description>
```

tag while source B uses a

```
<summary>
```

tag.

Source A specifies the product link as

```
<link href="http://..."></link>
```

while source B uses

```
<link>http://...</link>
```

Comment: xslt is probably what you're looking for.

Comment: Thanks. I don't suppose you know if one exists for Google Base XML?

Comment: Show your sources, otherwise this did not happen (most likely those sources (at least one of them) is not following Google Base XML Schema http://www.google.com/base/base.xsd )

Comment: Agreed. So I managed to find an alternate way - each source has a CSV file as well :)